# How to authenticate user with google on page load whitout login button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm working on a project where I need to include Google authentication, but my superior would like to have it in a different way, when the page loads, it checks if the user is Logged In into Google, and if it is then gets the users email address.

My question is that is it possible to send an authorization request on page load to Google, and authenticate the user without the user have to click on any button?

Comment: Nice idea, but - bad user interface design/experience. Probably you can not do that. You better just remember the returning client and log him automatically... but you can avoid the at least one time login.

Comment: I guess it's a bit difficult because to use `OAUTH`, the browser redirects to the google page where the user's permission is asked and only if user is okay, he is redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.Even if user is logged in Google in other tab for example to be able to access user email address you must ask user for permissions.
After user confirms this then you will receive access token that you can use to make request to google and access users email adress and other data.